# How do I install a 32-bit Java runtime on an amd64 server with multiarch?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, java, multiarch, jre

I'm a long time Ubuntu user, but I haven't been following the community for the last several versions. I just did fresh default minimal amd64 install of Oneiric and I need a 32-bit JRE for a particular application. I last did this on 10.10, so I am not familiar with the multiarch stuff. Instead of installing ia32-libs, I read a bit and tried:

```
aptitude install default-jre-headless:i386
```

But that just got me:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre-headless{b} openjdk-6-jre-headless{ab} 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.3 MB of archives. After unpacking 82.1 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  default-jre-headless: Depends: java-common which is a virtual package.
  openjdk-6-jre-headless: Depends: openjdk-6-jre-lib (>= 6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5) which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: ca-certificates-java which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: tzdata-java which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: libcups2 but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: liblcms1 but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     default-jre-headless [Not Installed]               
2)     openjdk-6-jre-headless [Not Installed]             



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
```

Is aptitude not installing the 32-bit versions of the dependencies?  What is the right way to do this? I'll likely want both a 64-bit and a 32-bit JRE if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiarch support is still in very early stages. In 11.10, there was enough multiarch for flash and skype. In 12.04, it'll cover everything ia32-libs did, but not everything else. That'll take years, although the most popular bits will probably come first.

Comment: Will this answer stay true forever?..

Comment: Coverage will probably never be complete, but most of the core libraries are multiarched these days.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: I can't find a way to do this, I just went with the 32-bit JRE package from Sun and installed it into /opt.

I had similar problems installing WINE. But that appears to be just about aptitude being broken w.r.t. multiarch, apt-get install WINE worked just fine.